# Open port on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, firewall, port, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to setup an SSH tunnel on my mac.

To do so I need to open a port (let's say 5901). What I have found online suggests modifying the /etc/pf.conf adding at the end of the file this line:

> pass in proto tcp from any to any port 5901

and rebooting the service using this command:

> sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf

But an error occurs:

> pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules present in
>   the main ruleset added by the system at startup. See /etc/pf.conf for
>   further details. No ALTQ support in kernel ALTQ related functions
>   disabled

The firewall is active and telnet is reporting the port as closed.

Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you
     Vito

Comment: Are you running a service that listens on port 5901, and if so is it listening to that port on all IP addresses and versions (IPv4 and IPV6)? Are you trying to connect from the same computer, another computer in the same local network, or from across the Internet? What address are you using to connect?

Comment: Dear Gordon, 

Thank you for your reply.

I am trying to open an ssh tunnel:

ssh -vvv -N -C -L localhost:5901:remote:5901 remote@remote_host

but ssh reports:

debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0

I wanna connect to a PC across the internet. 

I am trying to use my local address of my laptop connected to the router of my home and a remote pc with a public address.

Comment: Using `-L localhost:5901:...` listens only on the local loopback address (for both IPv4 and IPv6), so that tunnel will only be reachable from the local computer and the firewall is irrelevant. But it might have to do with a firewall at the remote computer (or port 5901 not having a service listening, or...). If you ssh to the remote computer and then run `telnet remote 5901` (using the same "remote" address you used in the forward), does it work?